# Cannot import migration data into a MariaDB database

Tags: mysql, mariadb, keycloak

I'm trying to import some exported migration data into a `MariaDB` database.

I could successfully do the import into the `H2` database.

But when trying to import in the `MariaDB` one, it creates `87` tables in the database instead of `91` tables, and also ends up in error:

```
2018-04-22 14:13:33,275 INFO  [org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) Initializing database schema. Using changelog META-INF/jpa-changelog-master.xml
2018-04-22 14:18:22,393 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0348: Timeout after [300] seconds waiting for service container stability. Operation will roll back. Step that first updated the service container was 'add' at address '[
    ("core-service" => "management"),
    ("management-interface" => "http-interface")
]'
```

This new log chunk shows it takes almost 5 mn. It's way too long.

More from the stacktrace:

```
16:16:55,690 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./auth: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./auth: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003325: Failed to construct public org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication(javax.servlet.ServletContext,org.jboss.resteasy.core.Dispatcher)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:84)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003325: Failed to construct public org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication(javax.servlet.ServletContext,org.jboss.resteasy.core.Dispatcher)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:162)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.createProviderInstance(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2298)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.createApplication(ResteasyDeployment.java:340)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:253)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:120)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:36)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:250)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:565)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:536)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:578)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to update database
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.update(LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.java:102)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.update(LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.java:67)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.update(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:322)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.migration(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:292)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.lambda$lazyInit$0(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:179)
    at org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.suspendJtaTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:544)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.lazyInit(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:130)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.create(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:78)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.create(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:56)
    at org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakSession.getProvider(DefaultKeycloakSession.java:163)
    at org.keycloak.models.jpa.JpaRealmProviderFactory.create(JpaRealmProviderFactory.java:51)
    at org.keycloak.models.jpa.JpaRealmProviderFactory.create(JpaRealmProviderFactory.java:33)
    at org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakSession.getProvider(DefaultKeycloakSession.java:163)
    at org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.RealmCacheSession.getDelegate(RealmCacheSession.java:144)
    at org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.RealmCacheSession.getMigrationModel(RealmCacheSession.java:137)
    at org.keycloak.migration.MigrationModelManager.migrate(MigrationModelManager.java:76)
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.migrateModel(KeycloakApplication.java:246)
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.migrateAndBootstrap(KeycloakApplication.java:187)
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication$1.run(KeycloakApplication.java:146)
    at org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:227)
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.<init>(KeycloakApplication.java:137)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:150)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set META-INF/jpa-changelog-2.1.0.xml::2.1.0::bburke@redhat.com:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: java.sql.SQLException: IJ031040: Connection is not associated with a managed connection: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk8.WrappedConnectionJDK8@55194ba1
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:573)
    at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:51)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:73)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:210)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:190)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:186)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.updateChangeSet(LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.java:135)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.update(LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.java:88)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: java.sql.SQLException: IJ031040: Connection is not associated with a managed connection: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk8.WrappedConnectionJDK8@55194ba1
    at liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection.getURL(JdbcConnection.java:79)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:62)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:122)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1247)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1230)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:548)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: IJ031040: Connection is not associated with a managed connection: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk8.WrappedConnectionJDK8@55194ba1
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.lock(WrappedConnection.java:164)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.getMetaData(WrappedConnection.java:913)
    at liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection.getURL(JdbcConnection.java:77)
    ... 65 more
```

The export command was:

```
$KEYCLOAK_HOME/bin/standalone.sh -Dkeycloak.migration.action=export -Dkeycloak.migration.provider=dir -Dkeycloak.migration.dir=exported_realms -Dkeycloak.migration.strategy=OVERWRITE_EXISTING
```

The import command that fails is:

```
$KEYCLOAK_HOME/bin/standalone.sh -Dkeycloak.migration.action=export -Dkeycloak.migration.provider=dir -Dkeycloak.migration.dir=exported_realms -Dkeycloak.migration.strategy=OVERWRITE_EXISTING
```

Here is the data source used in the `standalone/configuration/standalone.xml` file:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:/jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS" pool-name="KeycloakDS" enabled="true">
  <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/keycloak?useSSL=false&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8</connection-url>
  <driver>mysql</driver>
  <pool>
    <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
    <max-pool-size>15</max-pool-size>
  </pool>
  <security>
    <user-name>keycloak</user-name>
    <password>xxxxxx</password>
  </security>
  <validation>
    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
    <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
    <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
  </validation>
</datasource>
```

I'm using `keycloak-3.4.1.Final` and `mariadb-10.1.24` on a java version `1.8.0_60`.

Running the `./mysqltuner.pl` utility shows:

```
-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 2.0G/222.6M
[OK] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size: 256.0M * 2/2.0G should be equal 25%
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 2
[--] InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk Size not used or defined in your version
[!!] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 63.85% (802 hits/ 1256 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 0% (1 hits/ 0 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 1 writes)

General recommendations:
    Control warning line(s) into /home/stephane/programs/install/mariadb/mariadb.error.log file
    1 CVE(s) found for your MySQL release. Consider upgrading your version !
    MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Dedicate this server to your database for highest performance.
    Reduce or eliminate unclosed connections and network issues
    Consider installing Sys schema from https://github.com/mysql/mysql-sys
Variables to adjust:
    query_cache_size (=0)
    query_cache_type (=0)
    query_cache_limit (> 1M, or use smaller result sets)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing the MySQLTuner utility:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl/master/mysqltuner.pl
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl/master/basic_passwords.txt -O basic_passwords.txt
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl/master/vulnerabilities.csv -O vulnerabilities.csv
chmod +x mysqltuner.pl
./mysqltuner.pl
```

I understood my database server was poorly configured and writes were too slow, resulting in a timeout of the import operation.

I then configured the `my.cnf` file with the directives:

```
skip-name-resolve = 1
performance_schema = 1
innodb_log_file_size = 256M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 2
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
thread_cache_size = 4
```

The one directive that allowed the import to complete successfully was:

```
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
```

UPDATE: I commented out the `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2` directive, so as to trigger the error again. I could then collect the additional information as requested by the bellow comment.

```
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 14761
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 14761
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited

$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3743        2751         116         115         875         700
Swap:          4450          74        4376
```

The complete `my.cnf` file:

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode        = NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION # This is strict mode: NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
socket          = /home/stephane/programs/install/mariadb/tmp/mariadb.sock
user            = stephane
basedir         = /home/stephane/programs/install/mariadb
datadir         = /home/stephane/programs/install/mariadb/data
log-bin         = /home/stephane/programs/install/mariadb/mariadb.bin.log
log-error       = /home/stephane/programs/install/mariadb/mariadb.error.log
general-log-file     = /home/stephane/programs/install/mariadb/mariadb.log
slow-query-log-file  = /home/stephane/programs/install/mariadb/mariadb.slow.queries.log
long_query_time = 1
log-queries-not-using-indexes = 1
innodb_file_per_table = 1
sync_binlog = 1
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
wait_timeout            = 28800 # amount of seconds during inactivity that MySQL will wait before it will close a connection on a non-interactive connection
interactive_timeout     = 28800 # same, but for interactive sessions
max_allowed_packet = 128M
net_write_timeout = 180
skip-name-resolve = 1
thread_cache_size = 4
#skip-networking
#skip-host-cache
#bulk_insert_buffer_size = 1G
performance_schema = 1
innodb_log_file_size = 128M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 2
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
[client]
socket          = /home/stephane/programs/install/mariadb/tmp/mariadb.sock
default-character-set = utf8mb4
[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4
```

The [environment status and variables](https://pastebin.com/9F2v0s6b)

The other commands output:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1,9G     0  1,9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           375M  6,1M  369M   2% /run
/dev/sda1        17G  7,6G  8,4G  48% /
tmpfs           1,9G   21M  1,9G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1,9G     0  1,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda5       438G   51G  365G  13% /home
tmpfs           375M   16K  375M   1% /run/user/1000

$ top - 19:22:22 up  1:13,  1 user,  load average: 2,04, 1,27, 1,17
Tasks: 223 total,   1 running, 222 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  2,9 us,  0,6 sy,  0,0 ni, 73,3 id, 23,1 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,1 si,  0,0 st
KiB Mem :  3833232 total,   196116 free,  2611360 used,  1025756 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  4557820 total,  4488188 free,    69632 used.   985000 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                   
10399 stephane  20   0 4171240 448816  25724 S   3,6 11,7   0:39.78 java                                                                      
 8110 stephane  20   0 1217152 111392  40800 S   2,3  2,9   0:54.32 chrome                                                                    
 8290 stephane  20   0 1276140 148024  41360 S   2,0  3,9   0:43.52 chrome                                                                    
 1272 root      20   0  373844  45632  28108 S   1,0  1,2   1:37.31 Xorg                                                                      
 3172 stephane  20   0  729100  37060  22116 S   1,0  1,0   0:14.50 gnome-terminal-                                                           
11433 stephane  20   0 3163040 324680   9288 S   1,0  8,5   0:05.09 mysqld                                                                    
 8260 stephane  20   0 1242104 142028  42292 S   0,7  3,7   0:31.93 chrome                                                                    
 8358 stephane  20   0 1252060  99884  40876 S   0,7  2,6   0:34.06 chrome                                                                    
12580 root      20   0 1095296  78872  36456 S   0,7  2,1   0:10.29 dockerd                                                                   
   14 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,3  0,0   0:00.01 watchdog/1                                                                
 2461 stephane  20   0 1232332 203156  74752 S   0,3  5,3   4:29.75 chrome                                                                    
 7437 stephane  20   0 3509576 199780  46004 S   0,3  5,2   0:20.66 skypeforlinux                                                             
 8079 stephane  20   0 1243784 130948  38848 S   0,3  3,4   0:23.82 chrome                                                                    
 8191 stephane  20   0 1146672  72848  37536 S   0,3  1,9   0:12.41 chrome                                                                    
 8501 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,3  0,0   0:00.80 kworker/0:1                                                               
 9331 stephane  20   0   46468   4164   3380 R   0,3  0,1   0:01.38 top                                                                       
    1 root      20   0  220368   8492   6404 S   0,0  0,2   0:02.26 systemd                                                                   
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kthreadd                                                                  
    4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H                                                              
    6 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 mm_percpu_wq    

$ iostat -x 
Linux 4.13.0-39-generic (stephane-ThinkPad-X201)    22/05/2018  _x86_64_    (4 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           8,65    0,92    2,17    8,73    0,00   79,53

Device            r/s     w/s     rkB/s     wkB/s   rrqm/s   wrqm/s  %rrqm  %wrqm r_await w_await aqu-sz rareq-sz wareq-sz  svctm  %util
sda             42,68   23,49    816,72    905,13     8,40    36,83  16,45  61,06   17,18   52,96   1,98    19,14    38,53   4,31  28,53

$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3743        2571         137         107        1034         924
Swap:          4450          68        4382
```

The top, iostat and free commands were executed during the import migration script execution.

The full [MySQL Tuner output](https://pastebin.com/chaxhJLk)

Comment: @Stephanie Additional information second request, please. Post on pastebin.com or here. COMPLETE (not edited) my.cnf-ini Text results of: A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; C) COMPLETE MySQLTuner.com report if readily available Optional very helpful information, if available includes - htop OR top for most active apps, iostat -x when system is busy for an idea of IOPS, df -h for a linux/unix free space list by device, free -m for a linux/unix free memory report for your server analysis.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Sorry for the delay. I had hurt my back a bit and was slow for some weeks. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Yes I had done so as stated in the May 27 at 8:18  comment. Again, the solution has been posted long ago.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of this error is because the linux Server needs increment the number of open files.
Really, you need first tune your bdd, because when is very slowly this cause a timeout. 
Check the attribute "open files" with  the command:

```
ulimit -n
```

In my case I use 200000.

Please use [this example](https://gist.github.com/luckydev/b2a6ebe793aeacf50ff15331fb3b519d):

```
# maximum capability of system
user@ubuntu:~$ cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
708444

# available limit
user@ubuntu:~$ ulimit -n
1024

# To increase the available limit to say 200000
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo vim /etc/sysctl.conf

# add the following line to it
fs.file-max = 200000

# run this to refresh with new config
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo sysctl -p

# edit the following file
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo vim /etc/security/limits.conf

# add following lines to it

* soft  nofile  200000   
* hard  nofile  200000
www-data  soft  nofile  200000
www-data  hard  nofile  200000
root soft nofile 200000   
root hard nofile 200000

# edit the following file
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo vim /etc/pam.d/common-session

# add this line to it
session required pam_limits.so

# logout and login and try the following command
user@ubuntu:~$ ulimit -n
200000

# now you can increase no.of.connections per Nginx worker
# in Nginx main config /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
worker_connections 200000;
worker_rlimit_nofile 200000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ulimit -a report indicates 'open files' are at 1024
ulimit -n 10000     would expand your capacity to better accommodate MySQL.

In the 1,318 seconds reported in SHOW GLOBAL STATUS, there we
33 com_rollback items counted and
1 handler_rollback   possibly all the result of the java failure documented above.

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf-ini [mysqld] section to possibly speed up the processing.

## Suggestions by Back To Basics, Inc. 05/24/2018 for this IMPORT processing

```
max_connect_errors=10  # why tolerate 100 hacker/cracker attempts?
thread_cache_size=30  # from 4  to ensure threads ready to go
innodb_io_capacity_max=10000  # from 2000 default, for SSD vs HDD
innodb_io_capacity=5000  # from 200 default, for SSD vs HDD
have_symlink=NO  # to protect server from RANSOMWARE crowd
innodb_flush_neighbors=0  # from 1, no need when SSD - no rotational delay
innodb_lru_scan_depth=512  # from 1024 to conserve CPU see v8 refman
innodb_print_all_deadlocks=ON  # from OFF in error log for proactive correction
innodb_purge_threads=4  # from 1 to speed purge processing
log_bin=OFF  # from ON unless you need to invest the resources during import
log_warnings=2  # from 1 for addl info on aborted_connection in error log
max_join_size=1000000000  # from upper limit of 4 Billion rows
max_seeks_for_key=32  # rather than allowing optimizer to search 4 Billion ndx's.
max_write_lock_count=16  # to allow RD after nn lcks rather than 4 Billion
performance_schema=OFF  # from ON for this IMPORT processing speed
log_queries_not_using_indexes=0  # not likely to look at these, for import
```

Copy and paste at END of [mysqld} for quick test, weed out duplicate
same variable names when time permits from the top of [mysqld].
These will not resolve the error documented but should speed up the processing.

PLease provide feedback when time permits.

Comment: I followed your instructions and copied and pasted the above content at the bottom of the [mysqld] section, removing any duplicates it had. Of course, I had also reverted back the `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit` property to its original value of `1`. The import failed as in the question description, with the same described behavior and same error message. I then changed the `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit` to the value of `2` and the import succeeded as described in my answer.

Comment: @stephane How long did the import take, before and after?  Thanks for your details on being successful.  For additional assistance contact information is in my profile.

Comment: @stephane  Would you consider posting the above comment on the blog at mysqlservertuning dot com?  Thank You.

Comment: The response time felt like being the same. I could post a comment. Can you be more precise as what to post from this thread and where exactly in your website ?